# Fabric SDK Go Conflict with Fabric 1.4.12 Protos - "Message Already Registered" Error

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-fabric-sdk-go

I'm encountering an issue while working with Hyperledger Fabric 1.4.12. The problem arises when I try to run my Go application, and it throws a panic with the following error message:

```
panic: proto: message msp.SerializedIdentity is already registered
```

Upon investigating further, I have identified that the root cause of this error is a conflict between the fabric-sdk-go and the protos used in Fabric 1.4.12. It appears that fabric-sdk-go has a dependency on fabric-protos-go, which clashes with the protos already included in Fabric 1.4.12 source code.

This conflict results in the duplication of the `msp.SerializedIdentity` message registration, leading to the "message already registered" error.

Here are the steps I have taken so far to address the issue:

1. Upgraded fabric-sdk-go and fabric-protos-go to their latest versions.
2. Verified that there is only one version of fabric-protos-go installed in my project.
3. Attempted to clean and rebuild the project.

Unfortunately, these steps did not resolve the issue. Therefore, I believe that the root cause lies in the incompatibility between fabric-sdk-go v1.0.0-beta1 and the protos already present in Fabric 1.4.12.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just trying to understand your usage scenario... how come you have both fabric-sdk-go and the fabric package as dependencies of your project? Fabric itself is not intended to be consumed as a library so, provided the wire-level serialized messages are compatible, it shouldn't matter if fabric-sdk-go (gRPC client) and fabric (gRPC server) depend on different versions of fabric-protos-go (protobuf bindings).

Comment: @bestbeforetoday I'm moving and old project from using Gopath to go modules. I have the main module where I use fabric-sdk-go. Only one place fabric is imported as a package to use fabric/common/utils. Then there is the chaincode sub module or package, which is inside the main module and is heavily using the fabric as a package. So when I try to get dependencies and build the main module, it gets all the modules needed in the chaincode package and SDK package. Something ontheway is causing the mentioned conflict. Thnks for taking the time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!

I have the chaincode directory inside the main module, which shouldn't be a problem if it was not imported in the main module to get some struct types. Once I removed the imports the issue was gone.